# How to Virtualize Grid panel

Tags: wpf

I am using Grid as Items panel template for Items control as my grid has 100 rows and columns, its taking so much time to render. so How we can Virtualize grid panel like stackpanel

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `VirtualizingPanel` class?

[MSDN Virtual Panel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Another option is to use datagrid which will let you do what you are trying to accomplish.

There is a great article out there which I found.

[Custom Panels in Silverlight/WPF Part 4: Virtualization](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2009/09/custom-panels-in-silverlight-wpf-part-4-virtualization/)